# Is it possible to scale F-Curves linearly?

Tags: fcurves

In the graph edutor, I press S then Y then 2. It doesn't multiply the x location of the key frames by 2. Instead, it multiplies every single key frame by a factor and I don't know what is this factor or what the equation is.

I added the generator modifier to an F-Curve. The original value of the X location = 1 (at a specific key frame). According to the equation in the modifier (Y = 1 X + 0). The, X location should not be changed (remains 1). But now it’s 201 and I don’t know why. I just would like to scale my F-Curve by a linear factor. How can I do this? I tried Factorized and Expanded polynomial but they are the same. Their equations give very high output numbers.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the role of X in the graph editor.  The x axis is not any X transform channel of any of your objects.  The X is the frame count.  If you scale the X by a linear factor, what you're doing is slowing things down.  If you want to do that, set the cursor to 0,0, pivot point to cursor, select all, and s x 2 enter.

Comment: I understand it very well but I mistyped it. It should be scaling a long the y-axis in the graph editor which controls the x-location if an object in the 3D viewport. Sorry about that. @Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What scaling does depends on your pivot point for that graph editor viewport.  Try this: set your pivot point to 2D cursor.  Open a sidebar in the graph editor.  On the "view" tab, set the cursor location to 0,0.  Then select all and scale by 2.0 in the Y axis.  This will scale all the points about 0,0, which means multiplying all values by 2.  Is that what you want?

(Not at all clear what you expect to happen with your generator.  Again, the x in question here is frame count.  The X is an input, and if it's 201, it's because you're currently looking at frame 201.)

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. The pivot point is what I was missing. Thanks for explaining it. It's a great answer and have much info. God bless you,